# EMR and Common Crawl Valid Segments

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am running an EMR cluster with a mapper.py and reducer.py on a valid segment set from Common Crawl and I have two issues:

If I use the direct S3 URL to the TextData file the steps work, but I get empty results like this:

Input URL:

**s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690169105/textData-00060**

Output:
[image]

But if I specify a range of segments in my URL like this:

**s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690169105/textData-00060[0-9]**

The step fails with the following log error:

Error Launching job : Input Pattern s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690169105/textData-00060[0-9] matches 0 files

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to match 000600 to 000609? or 00060 to 00069

Comment: Im just trying to get the output to contain data. Ive seen it done with a range of files [0-9], but that fails when I run it and the other url with just the textData contains output with no data